# Read file from "extsdcard"

Tags: android

I have some music in both sdcard and extsdcard

I use Cursor to list them:

```
Uri deviceMusic = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(deviceMusic, null,
            selection, null, sortOrder);

if (cursor == null || cursor.isClosed()) {
        return;
    }

// Get music information
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       // File path
       String data = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

then i use the code below to judge the type of music:

```
public static String getFileHeader(String filePath) {
    FileInputStream is = null;
    String value = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        byte[] b = new byte[3];
        is.read(b, 0, b.length);
        value = bytesToHexString(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != is) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

this method works fine on sdcard,

but encounter "FileNotFoundException" on extsdcard

so i try to check the file with hard code:

```
File file = new File(
            "/storage/extSdCard/(I Can't Help) Falling In Love With You - UB 40.mp3");

    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.i("", "");
    }
```

it returns false when the above code in the loop of

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
```

but when i hard code in other place such as onCreate

it return true...

what's that situation?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal. check this don't use hardcoded paths

Comment: hardcoded paths is use for check the file in extsdcard is exist or not, my problem is, a file exist in extsdcard but return FileNotFoundException when in the loop but work fine out of the loop

Comment: I have the same problem for (only) mp3's in extSdCard, in internal (sdcard) I've no problem. I get the mp3 path from the DATA column of the cursor as you but I cannot access to the mp3. How can I do?